# Django rest framework - thumbnail image serializer

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

My case is basic: I want to send urls of thumbnails to the client within responses to AJAX requests. I have custom image fields that deserialize base64 encoded images from the client and sorl_thumbnail as thumbnail engine. In my views I want to instantiate deserializer with arbitrary options for thumbnailer.

What is a common techniques for that in Django REST framework?

upd
The main problem is how to pass arguments about dimensions, format, quality, etc, to serializer? In one place I might need small thumbnail of the picture, in other bigger thumbnail.

Now I see two approaches:
- Make a factory which will produce serializer with given options for thumbnail-fields
- Send thumbnail options within AJAX requests and make serializer able to read and follow them.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ways you could go about this, depending on a lot of information you don't give, but, perhaps look into using a [SerializerMethodField](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields.html#serializermethodfield) in your serializer.

The basic idea would be to create a method that is able to return the appropriate URL for the thumbnail given the object instance and bind the SerializerMethodField to that.

By default DRF's [GenericViews](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views.html) pass the request through to serializers via the [`context` parameter](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers.html#including-extra-context). This enables you to access the request with such as `request = self.context.get('request', None)`. From there you can read the thumbnail options as you suggest.

Hopefully that's enough to get you started.